# Cardinality of a set whose elements are not in the domain of f?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $f: D \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function defined by $f(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-25}}{x+5}$, where $D \subset \mathbb{Z}$. Let $A$ be the set of integers which are not in the domain of $f$, then find the cardinality of the set $A$

I suppose the cardinality of set $A$ is 0? Because the domain of $f$ is $D \subset \mathbb{Z}$ and the constraint of set $A$ is integers not in the domain of $f$... Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: The domain is strictly smaller than $D$. E.g. $f(-5)$ and $f(0)$ are undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the specific formula through which your function $f$ is defined. This will tell you what the "natural" domain of your function is, which is the largest subset of the integers for which your function is well-defined.

First of all, let's just write this explicit formula down:
$$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-25}}{x+5}$$

Observe that $x = -5 \notin D$.Otherwise, the fraction above would be undefined as we would be dividing by $0$. Now, we also need it to be the case that:
$$x^2-25 \geq 0$$
This implies that $|x| \geq 5$. In other words, the integers $\{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\}$ are the only ones which cannot be in the domain of $f$. The cardinality of this set is $10$.